LinearRegression with large number of features and targets, but small number of samples runs out of memory
I have a huge number of feature and targets, but small number of samples. It turns out, that in such case a simple linear regression with numpy.linalg.pinv works much better than sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.
For example, n_features=n_targets=30000, and n_samples=2:
X = np.random.random((2, 30000))
Y = np.random.random((2, 30000))
x = np.random.random((1, 30000)) 

y = Y.T  @  (np.linalg.pinv(X.T)  @ x.T) # works fast and use a little memory

reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(X,Y) # slow and uses a lot of memory
y2 = reg.predict(x)

np.linalg.norm(y2 - y) < 1e-12

The problem is that reg.coef_.shape is (30000, 30000). So LinearRegression don't exploit low-rank of the regression.
Is there any way to get an analog of a simple pinv solution with sklearn framework?
I tried to search, but failed to find anything usefull.

Consider adding 1)L1 regularization 2)L2 regularization 3)PCA for dimension reduction and 4)SGD

@SimpleLife How L1 is supposed to help? Add more complexity?

@SimpleLife How to add PCA ? Transform everything manually?

To Promote sparsity in the coefficient matrix, effectively pushing coefficients of less important features towards zero.

Before promoting sparsity, Lasso builds the same n_features x n_targets matris. It is even slower than LinearRegression

Valid points. I would suggest to look into truncated SVD and linear regression.

To get others started, sklearn's LinearRegression notes that it's just a wrapper of scipy's lstsq, which in turn uses LAPACK, by default (and in the case of LinearRegression) using gelsd.  There are some sklearn github Issues discussing adding optional parameters to control that, but I don't know enough to say what might be more useful in this setting.

I solved the problem using sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge class with alpha=1e-15, kernel='rbf' parameters. For my task it shows the same  speed, memory requirements, and accuracy as the pinv-based solution. The code is compact too:
reg = KernelRidge(alpha=1e-15, kernel='rbf')
reg.fit(X, Y)
y3 = reg.predict(x)

I know, that it is not a linear model, but it works as well. Perhaps there is some kernel that works the same way as a linear regression. I think the polynomial kernel with degree=1 should work that way, but I haven't tried it.
